# Custom validation with RESTful APIs

Tags: java, rest, validation, jersey

I am newbie in Java world (came from .Net background). I created a RESTful service using Jersey framework. it has couple of methods. Following is the sample code snippet for Customer service. There are couple more services in my code.

```
@Path("/CustomerService")
public interface ICustomerService {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getCustomerInfo")
    Response query(String constraints);

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getCustomerDetails")
    Response fetchDetails(String customerID);

}
```

I have some validation logic which I would like to perform at each API which is exposed to the client. I C# world we can define own validation logic. Something like following, This can be applied at method or controller level.

```
[MyValdationLogic()]
```

What is the equivalent in Java? How can I write code which can be applied at multiple places over the method.

Also I do not want to allow admin to play with that configuration. I found there is something called as filters but this gets configured in config file. admin can disable it.

Comment: Same thing in Java: this is done with bean validation annotations. Jersey specific support can be found at https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Validator class` and use that `Validator class` on your `bean` for validation. Although, the process is bit lengthy.

Following is one example of doing this -

**Jersey Resource**

```
@POST
@Path("/addEmp")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String doOrder(@BeanParam final @Valid Employee emp) {

    // Some implementation here
}
```

**Sample Bean -**
Suppose, I want to apply validation on address i.e. either address or city or postcode must be there.

```
@Address
public final class Employee {

    @FormDataParam("id")
    private String id;

    @FormDataParam("address")
    private String address;

    @FormDataParam("city")
    private String city;

    @FormDataParam("postcode")
    private String postcode;

        // Other member variables

        // Getters and setters

}
```

**Address Annotation -**
Define custom Address Annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AddressValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Address {

    String message() default "Address required";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Validator Class -**
Here is the validator class contains actual validation logic -

```
public class AddressValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Address, Employee> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Employee emp, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    // Check for at least one value
    if((emp.getAddress() != null && !emp.getAddress().equals("") ||
            (emp.getCity() != null && !emp.getCity().equals("")) ||
            (emp.getPostcode() != null && !emp.getPostcode().equals("")))) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
    }
    public void initialize(Address emp) {
          ...
    }
}
```

By this way, you can create reusable `Validator class`. Instead of taking Employee directly in this `Validator class`, you can take `Object class` or some parent class and then change the logic accordingly.

You can check more details in [bean-validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)